# Checking format and characters in file from stdin in C?

Tags: c, validation, format

I currently have a program where I read in a .txt file like so: `./myprogram < input.txt` and put each character in my array. This code looks something like this:

```
char myArray[SIZE_ROW][SIZE_COL];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_ROW; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_COL; j++) {
        fscanf(stdin, "%c ", &myArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Before I fill `myArray` I would like to make sure that `input.txt` has the format of `SIZE_ROW` characters by `SIZE_COL` characters, for for example if `SIZE_ROW` and `SIZE_COL` were both equal to 4, so a valid `input.txt` could look something like this:

```
.p..
k...
..q.
.P..
```

while an invalid `input.txt` could look like this:

```
.....q.
..k..p
p..
```

While I'm checking the format, I would also like to make sure that `input.txt` only contains the characters `q`, `k` and `p` for example.

I have tried using `fgets()` to read in the file line by line, but when I do this, using `scanf` afterwards to fill `myArray` seems to not work. I also do *not* know the name of the file beforehand, so the only way I can open it is as shown above: `./myprogram < input.txt`.

Comment: If you read lines with `fgets()`, then the next step is to process what `fgets()` read, maybe via `sscanf()`, not to attempt to read the lines anew via `scanf()`.

Comment: If you do not know the name of the file beforehand, the only way to open it is not: `./myprogram < input.txt`. You can use command line arguments to open the file using its name which is passed as a command line argument at runtime like: `./myprogram input.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pseudo code to get you started.

```
int Read_EsoFile(char myArray[RSIZE][CSIZE], FILE *istream) {
   for each row (0 to RSIZE -1)
     char buf[CSIZE+3];
     read line using fgets and detect EOF
     truncate potential trailing \n
     test if valid 
       length == CSIZE?
       elmenet only `q k p`?
     save in myArray[i]

  return success status
}

// example usage
char myArray[RSIZE][CSIZE];
int result = Read_EsoFile(myArray, stdin);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this out and report back if I got it working or not.

Comment: If `buf` passed the tests (length == COL_SIZE, qkp only), I would simple use `memcpy(myArray[i], buf, COL_SIZE)`

Comment: But then if `input.txt` has more than `SIZE_ROW` lines, then that wouldn't be detected, right?

Comment: That is a new requirement. (too many lines). Best to think out all requirements up front.   To detect if additional data exist, after the loop simply use `if (fgetc(stdin) == EOF) OHappyDay() else ExtraJunk();`

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I think I've got it working, but all I need is to check if `buf`only contains 'q', 'k' or 'p' for example. How can I do this?

Comment: @Esoemah Look up `strspn()`. it is made just for that.

Comment: I've been trying this code:
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) {
        if (strspn(buffer[i], ALLOWED) == 0) { 
            validity = 0;
        }

But this is giving me a segmentation fault. Just printing `buffer[i]` works, so why doesn't this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103652/discussion-between-chux-and-esoemah).

Answer (score 0):

> I also do not know the name of the file beforehand, so the only way I can open it is as shown above: `./myprogram < input.txt`.

If you do not know the name of the file beforehand, the only way to open it is not: `./myprogram < input.txt`. You can use command line arguments to open the file using its name which is passed as a command line argument at runtime, like: `./myprogram input.txt`.

Here is the code to do that, plus I have also applied all the checks that you asked for and then applied your code to get the data into the array and printed the array in the end to verify the contents:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE_ROW 4
#define SIZE_COL 4
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 if(argc == 2)
 {
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char* buffer = NULL;
  size_t n = SIZE_COL;
  int rows = 0, cols;
  int flag = 1;
  int i, j;
  while(!feof(f))
  {
   getline(&buffer, &n, f);
   if(strlen(buffer) > 1) // to skip blank lines
   {
    cols = strlen(buffer)-1;
    if(cols != SIZE_COL)
    {
     break;
    }
    for(i=0; i<cols; i++)
    {
     if(!(buffer[i] == '.' || buffer[i] == 'q' || buffer[i] == 'Q' || buffer[i] == 'k' || buffer[i] == 'K' || buffer[i] == 'p' || buffer[i] == 'P'))
     {
      break;
     }
    }
    if(i<cols)
    {
     flag = 0;
     break;
    }
    rows++;
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
   }
  }
  if(flag)
  {
   if(cols == SIZE_COL)
   {
    if(rows == SIZE_ROW)
    {
     rewind(f);
     char myArray[SIZE_ROW][SIZE_COL];
     for (i = 0; i < SIZE_ROW; i++)
     {
      for (j = 0; j < SIZE_COL; j++)
      {
        fscanf(f, "%c ", &myArray[i][j]);
      }
     }
     for (i = 0; i < SIZE_ROW; i++)
     {
      for (j = 0; j < SIZE_COL; j++)
      {
       printf("%c ", myArray[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
     }
    }
    else
    {
     printf("Row size is not %d.\n", SIZE_ROW);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    printf("Column size is %d not %d.\n", cols, SIZE_COL);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   printf("Invalid characters in file.\n");
  }
  fclose(f);
 }
 else
 {
  printf("Invalid Arguments! Please give file name as argument from command line.\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Ask me, if you do not understand anything in the code. You should call it like:

> ./myprogram input.txt